# PHP within PHP?

Tags: php, if-statement

Sorry if this sounds stupid! I'm using PHP to create certain sections of my website like the header, then echoing them on to every page. The problem is I want to put some PHP code within the section like this:

```
<?php
function makeHeader () {
$menuContent = <<<MENU

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> etc..........


<?php
if(isset($_SESSION['user']))
    {
            $user = isset($_SESSION['user']) ? $_SESSION['user'] : '';  
            echo "<a href='logout.php'>$user</a>";
        }
    else
        {
            echo "some text..";
        }
    ?> 

MENU;
$menuContent .= "\n";
return $menuContent;
}

?>
```

Is this possible? Its throwing up errors but starting from the `if(isset($_SESSION['user']))` line rather than the line above it..

Answer (score 2):

Use single or double quoted string instead of heredoc and it should be fine.

Comment: Or use an include. But yeah - generally I'm against HEREDOC syntax. I've never came across a single situation where it's been the right thing to use

Comment: @kissmyface Well, if we have to declare a string with numerous single and double quotes in it, heredoc does make things easier, although not a necessity.  ;)

Comment: I would argue that if you need to do that then you are 'doing it wrong', though I do appreciate that sometimes we have to work on other peoples code. sometimes that code is very bad. and sometimes we need to just 'get things done' :-)

Answer (score 1):

The error you are getting (but not mentioned) is probably a parse error. [`HEREDOC`](http://php.net/HEREDOC) syntax requires `{}` curly braces around variables, or no key quotes for simple array accesses. The workaround would be a  [`NOWDOC`](http://php.net/NOWDOC) string.

---

But you can't do it with that method anyway. PHP code in string context doesn't run. And it's pointless to apply any workarounds. Just use an include script instead of a HEREDOC and use [`ob_start`](http://php.net/ob_start) and [`ob_get_clean`](http://php.net/ob_get_clean) for capturing the output.

Answer (score 0):

is your code partial? or are you missing a closing } at the end of the function makeHeader? that would throw an exception on the "if" line. not to mention the missing closing php tag before the HTML up top.

I think the real issue is that you can't have and end tag and HTML within a function. if you REALLY need this then you can "echo" the HTML if needed. but I can't imagine you would want to write the entire doc from start to finish with echo statements.

would the following be suitable?

```
<?PHP
    session_start();
    $menuContent = <<<MENU;
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
    <?PHP
        echo $menuContent;
        if(isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
            $user = isset($_SESSION['user']) ? $_SESSION['user'] : '';  
            echo "<a href='logout.php'>$user</a>";
        } else {
            echo "some text..";
        }
    ?>
    etc..........
    </body>
</html>
```

or do you need to build it all in the menu section before?

Answer (score 0):

What is the errors?

Do you have session_start beforehand? Eg.:

```
function makeHeader () {  
session_start();
$menuContent = <<<MENU
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's possible, but I would be very interested to learn if I'm wrong.

As for what you're doing here, I think your life will be a million times easier if you just dump the PHP content for your header ing a file called `header.php` and include it like this:

```
<?php

  include("header.php"); // Containing the code you're trying to put into $menuContent

?>
```

There are also plenty of good templating frameworks (Smarty, Liquid, Mustache) out there if you want to avoid reinventing this wheel, though I understand the appeal.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function makeHeader () 
{
    $menuContent = "<!DOCTYPE html><html> etc.........." . 
    if(isset($_SESSION['user']))
    {
        $user = isset($_SESSION['user']) ? $_SESSION['user'] : '';  
        $menuContent .= "<a href='logout.php'>$user</a>";
    }
    else
    {
        $menuContent .= "some text..";
    }

    $menuContent .= "\n";
    return $menuContent;
```

}

Comment: You might need to recheck the code, but i hope u get the idea